# What is the use of man directive in package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am learning to npm/node and i found the field **man** which says that:

> Specify either a single file or an array of filenames to put in place for the man program to find.

[Reference Link.](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#man)

What is **man program**?

Can anyone explain in simple and easy words ?

Comment: `man` = `manual`

Comment: So it points the location to the file(s) that is the manual for this package ?

Comment: Yes, `man` program will get the file and use it as a manual to the application

Comment: But I never saw someone using it...

Comment: @LEQADA That's what you do when you need to RTM with no Internets.

Comment: @estus funny :D I meant using `man` in the `package.json`

Comment: It's specific to CLI packages, e.g.`man npm `. That's how Node embraces *nix. Node binaries aren't different than any other script executables (python, shell), and they behave like ones. `man` field guarantees that respective `man` documentation is installed automatically on package installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) is the standard UNIX command line tool for reading software manuals. `man` field is specific to *nix and remains unused on Windows, at least without [additional measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944434/where-is-the-man-program-for-windows-program-to-open-unix-man-pages).

It's expected that `man` field contains relative path to [`man` formatted page](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Man-Page/q3.html).

Answer (score 0):

[man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) is a CLI (an interface on Linux terminal) to the on-line reference manuals, aka [man-pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/). The man-pages project is created for documenting user manual that is by default built into most Linux distributions, versions and most other Unix-like operating systems during installation.