# Sphinx-build: using man builder name and checking whether created man pages are correctly displayed

Tags: python, python-sphinx, manpage

I am new to sphinx and I have currently used it to generate man pages using the man builder name through sphinx-build.

Man pages seems they are successfully generated since the final output after executing sphinx-build is:

```
build succeeded.

The manual pages are in build\man.
```

Within build\man folder I can see there are a lot of files called as filename.1

Anyway, I would like to check that those man pages have been correctly created and also I would like to check how they are displayed from Windows. So is there any way I can check this from Windows?

Comment: I have found mandoc and groff for windows.

Comment: @mzjn Okay, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found [mandoc](https://embedeo.org/ws/doc/man_windows/) and [groff](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/groff.htm) for Windows. Also groff is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944434/where-is-the-man-program-for-windows-program-to-open-unix-man-pages/70774882#70774882) as accepted answer.

**Usages from Windows command prompt**

**groff**:

groff -Tascii -mm your_file | more
for compatibility mode use:

groff -C -Tascii -mm your_file | more

groff for Windows can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/)

**mandoc**:

mandoc.exe manpage.1 | more